# Can the fallback language be different for different sites on a Sitecore instance?

Tags: sitecore, multilingual, fallback

In Sitecore, I want to set different fallback language for different sites.

For example,

- On Site 1: The Languages `fr-fr`, `de-de`, `da-dk`, `es-es`, `pt-pt` should fallback to `EN-GB`.
- On Site 2: The language `fr-fr`, `de-de`, `da-dk`, `es-es`, `pt-pt` should fallback to EN instead.

So, `fr-fr` should fallback to `en-GB` for Site 1 and `fr-fr` should fallback to `EN` for Site 2.

Please let me know if this is possible and if yes how? If there are customizations that are required to implement this, is it suggested to have such implementation?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a lot of customizations as long as the sites are in the same Sitecore instance. Will the items on site2 also have content in EN-GB, is it an option to have EN-BG fall back to EN?

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, the items in Site2 can have content in en-gb as well. This is just an example but ideally there could be other languages as well falling back to different languages in different sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the language fallback functionality either on item-level or field-level on the relevant sites and on the relevant items, fields, or templates.

The fallback language specified on a language definition item (located in `sitecore/system/Languages`) applies to all the fields and items across all sites configured on the same Sitecore instance that have language fallback enabled.

You can also set up **a chain of language fallbacks**. For example, you can specify the language `fr-FR` to fall back to `en-GB` and `en-GB` to fall back to `en`. If the version in `en-GB` does not exist for a particular item, then the version in `fr-FR` falls back to the version in `en`. Hopefully, this built-in logic will work for your case.

Otherwise, you will need to add a custom language to Sitecore, i.e. your own French one to support the language uniqueness to configure the language fallback at a site level.